# How to transfer files from a remote server to my Amazon S3 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have about 15 gigs of data in 5 files that I need to transfer to an Amazon S3 bucket, they are currently hosted on a remote server that I have no scripting or shell access to - I can only download them VIA an httpd link.

How can I transfer these files to my Amazon S3 bucket without first having to download them to my local machine then re-upload them to S3?

Comment: Create an EC2 instance, download them from there and then into S3?

Comment: ok .. I can get a shell on an EC2 then wget them?  how do I transfer them over to the S3 [or is that obvious once I set up an EC2?

Comment: There are various commandline tools you can use to push something to S3 once you have the files on an EC2 instance.  That'll probably be the easiest way.

Comment: ok - have the EC2 instance up - what are these command line tools?

Comment: There are a lot of them available.  What about http://s3tools.org/s3cmd ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automate the process, use AWS SDK.

Like in following case use AWS PHP SDK:

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;

$aws = Aws::factory('/path/to/your/config.php');
$s3 = $aws->get('S3');

$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => 'your-bucket-name',
    'Key'        => 'your-object-key',
    'SourceFile' => '/path/to/your/file.ext'
));
```

More details:

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx9BDFNDYYU4VF/Transferring-Files-To-and-From-Amazon-S3
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html

Answer (score 1):

Given that you only have 5 files, use the S3 file uploader http://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-east-1 (Actions, Upload) after you have downloaded the files to some intermediate machine.  EC2 running Windows might be the best solution as the upload to S3 would be very fast. You can download Chrome onto your EC2 instance from chrome.google.com, or use the existing web browser (IE) to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

**[1] SSH with keys**

```
    sh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -q -P ""
    cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Place this SSH key into your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file

```
    mkdir ~/.ssh 
    chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
    touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
    chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**[2] Snapshot ZFS, minimize transfer with LZMA, send with RSYNC**

```
    zfs snapshot zroot@150404-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT
    zfs list -t snapshot
```

Compress to file with lzma (more effective than bzip2)

```
    zfs send zroot@150404-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT | lzma -9 > /tmp/snapshots/zroot@150404-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT.lzma
    rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress --partial /tmp/snapshots/zroot@150404-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT.lzma <username>@<ip-address>:/
```

**[3] Speedup transfer with MBUFFER, send with ZFS Send/Recieve**
Start the receiver first. This listens on port 9090, has a 1GB buffer, and uses 128kb chunks (same as zfs):

```
    mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G -I 9090 | zfs receive zremote
```

Now we send the data, also sending it through mbuffer:

```
    zfs send -i zroot@150404-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT zremote@150404-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT | mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G -O <ip-address>:9090
```

**[4] Speedup transfer by only sending diff**

```
    zfs snapshot zroot@150404-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT
    zfs snapshot zroot@150405-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT [e.g. one day later]
    zfs send -i zroot@150404-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT zroot@150405-SNAPSHOT-ZROOT | zfs receive zremote/data
```

See also [my notes](http://www.blaeu.com/nl/doku.php/Notes)